# XSLT - match doesn't seem to work

Tags: xslt, match

I have this line in my transform:

`<xsl:template match="simplesect[@kind='since']">`

When I apply it to the following:

```
    <detaileddescription>
    <para><simplesect kind="since">
    <para>yesterday</para>
    </simplesect></para></detaileddescription>
```

I expect it to work.

However, I noticed that a space needs to exist between  and  tags.

So the following matches where the above doesn't

```
    <detaileddescription>
    <para> <simplesect kind="since">
    <para>yesterday</para>
    </simplesect></para></detaileddescription>
```

I'm stumped. Any ideas why or is here a call I make? Right now, the only solution I have is to find every instance of `<para><simplesect @kind="since">`and changing it to `<para> <simplesect @kind=since`. Notice the space between `<para>` and `<simplesect>`

Comment: It's working in both ways. Problem would be the way you are accessing it.

Comment: It's hard to tell you what's wrong with your XSLT if you only show us one line of it. The line you showed us looks fine, so the problem is likely elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

This stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="simplesect[@kind='since']">
        <modified><xsl:apply-templates/></modified>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to the first input, produces:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<detaileddescription>
    <para>
        <modified>
            <para>yesterday</para>
        </modified>
    </para>
</detaileddescription>
```